# Python. 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, requests

Есть некоторый код, который нормально запускается на своём компьютере. При попытке запустить его на vds сервере (Ubuntu 16), вылетает ошибка.
Сервер почти пустой, поэтому многовероятно, что там чего-то не хватает.

Подскажите из-за чего такое может быть, как это исправить.

Код:

[image: код]

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае `text` - свойство, а не метод. Уберите скобки после него.

Comment: Раньше так и делал. Но при такой модификации появляется другая ошибка. `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5048-5052: ordinal not in range(128)
`

Comment: @ОскарШарипов вторая ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к модулю requests. Это уже про кодировки.

Comment: Я и не говорил, что это ошибка requests. Я прошу помощи и предупредил, что сервер пустой, значит там чего-то не хватает.

Comment: интересно, что на компьтере под windows всё хорошо

Comment: это уже проблемы с локалью. лучше её настроить, но можно попробовать добавить вызов метода `.decode('utf-8')` к свойству `text`

Comment: @ArcherGodson 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. Сам удивлён

Comment: @ОскарШарипов если python2, попробуй unicode(...), т.е. вызовом функции.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, python3.6

Comment: @ArcherGodson, хех. Помогло `.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @ОскарШарипов да, соломенная моя голова, конечно же надо было encode() попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это не значит, что я не жду объяснений, почему надо `encode`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit]